# How should you use argparse to choose which action to perform and pass arguments to it?

Tags: python-3.4, argparse

I want to use the `argparse` library to parse some arguments but I'm struggling to work out what in the myriad of ways you can specify arguments is the simplest way to choose between a few actions. Different actions require different numbers of arguments.

Given the following calls I'd expect the following outputs:

```
> python MyClass.py action1 foo
Action 1: 12345 - foo

> python MyClass.py action2 20 30
Action 2: 12345 - 20 30
```

The following seems to work:

```
import argparse

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, someVar):
        self.someVar = someVar

    def Action1(self, intToPrint):
        print("Print 1: %d - %s"%(self.someVar,intToPrint))

    def Action2(self, firstNum, firstString):
        print("Print 2: %d - %d %s"%(self.someVar,firstNum, firstString))

def CallAction1(mc, args):
    mc.Action1(args.intToPrint)

def CallAction2(mc, args):
    mc.Action2(args.firstNum, args.firstString)

def Main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PythonArgumentParsing.py')
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='commands')

    action1Group = subparsers.add_parser('action1', help='action 1 help')
    action1Group.add_argument('intToPrint', type=str)
    action1Group.set_defaults(func=CallAction1)

    action2Group = subparsers.add_parser('action2', help='action 1 help')
    action2Group.add_argument('firstNum', type=int)
    action2Group.add_argument('firstString', type=str)
    action2Group.set_defaults(func=CallAction2)

    args = parser.parse_args()
    someVar = 12345
    mc = MyClass(someVar)
    args.func(mc, args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

...but it seems a little clunky to have to create a CallAction to pass arguments from the parser.

Is there any way to clean this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gather that you are just bothered by needing to write the `Call_Action...` functions which convert the `args` namespace into positional parameters for the method calls.

Using keyword parameters might eliminate this need.  The following hasn't been tested yet:

```
def Action1(self, intToPrint=None, **kwargs):
    print("Print 1: %d - %s"%(self.someVar,intToPrint))

def Action2(self, firstNum=None, firstString=None, **kwargs):
    print("Print 2: %d - %d %s"%(self.someVar,firstNum, firstString))
...
action1Group.set_defaults(func=MyClass.Action1)
...
args.func(mc, **vars(args))
```

If I've done this right I can pass the whole `vars(args)` dictionary to the method.  It will use the parameters that it needs, and ignore the rest.

`argparse` makes extensive use of the `**kwargs` method of passing parameters.

Comment: I gave that a shot but it gives me `TypeError: Action1() got multiple values for argument 'intToPrint'`. I'm not sure having to add `**kwargs` to every method I want to call is any less tricky.

Comment: Ah, change `mc.Action1` to `MyClass.Action1` and that appears to work :-)